# Web console for docker container

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, docker, runnable

### Situation

1. There is a data-only-container named: app-data
2. There is a copier container worker

Initially app/data was created and that's it, it's status is 'stop' / exited.
Then the copier worker copies some files to app/data as its volume, for example an `server.py`

Okay this was done like this:

```
docker run --rm --volumes-from app-data /somelocation/server.py ~/www/
```

the copier takes 2 arguments, the file to copy and where to copy

With that at hand, I can run a image named app/serve to server the file in the volume like so:

```
docker run --volumes-from app-data -d -P app/serve
```

the image entry point do this http-server, and workdir is same as the data volume, so it'll run

Hell yeah it works, and the python web app can be accessed in the host with a highport like so: 0.0.0.0:49124 because
the app/serve image expose ports 5000 which is used by the sever.py script

I had the above working, you can focus below.

So the app can run huh? But I want to do more complex things that just running the app (I ran the app using the remote api), what if I want to run the app using a web console connected to a docker container.

### My Idea of how would it be possible

1. use [term.js](https://github.com/chjj/term.js)
2. expose 2 ports e.g. (4000, 5000)
3. use port 4000, so that when term.js executes in port 4000, it'll generate a highport for the client to use in the web console socket connection
4. use port 5000 to allow whatever web application ran in port 5000 will be available in a another highport, to be accessed like so 0.0.0.0:49124

This is a prototype implementation of how runnable/dockworker do this, I am still new to nodejs that is why I cannot comprehend how they do it, could there be a less-featured simpler execution of this idea?

Comment: Very difficult to understand what you're looking for. I suspect it might be shipyard. See: http://shipyard-project.com/

Comment: Yeah, I've read shipyards implementation on this on, basically our idea is the same, it's just python and mine is javascript, using nodejs

Comment: Understood, but I would just caution against dismissing an existing solution based purely on its implementation language. Docker is implemented in Go, but we interact with it via its REST API. Shipyard also provides a REST API.